# Normalize vectors in the complex space : mean=0 and std-dev=1/sqrt(n)

Tags: python, fft, normalization, complex-numbers

I have a Vector Or bunch of vectors (stored in 2D array, by rows)

The vectors are generated as :

> MEAN=0, STD-DEV=1/SQRT(vec_len)

and before or after operations have to be normalized in the same form

I want to normalize them in the complex space.
Here is the wrapper of a function:

```
@staticmethod
def fft_normalize(x, dim=DEF_DIM):
    cx = rfft(x, dim=dim)
    ....
    rv = irfft(cx_proj, dim=dim)
    return rv
```

**help me fill the dots.**

Here is the real-value normalization that I use.

```
@staticmethod 
def normalize(a, dim=DEF_DIM): 
    norm=torch.linalg.norm(a,dim=dim)
    # if torch.eq(norm,0) : return torch.divide(a,st.MIN)
    if dim is not None : norm = norm.unsqueeze(dim)
    return torch.divide(a,norm)
```

---

```
In [70]: st.normalize(x + 3)
Out[70]: 
([[0.05, 0.04, 0.05,  ..., 0.04, 0.04, 0.04],
 [0.04, 0.04, 0.05,  ..., 0.05, 0.04, 0.05],
 [0.05, 0.04, 0.05,  ..., 0.04, 0.05, 0.04]])

In [71]: st.normalize(x + 5)
Out[71]: 
([[0.05, 0.04, 0.05,  ..., 0.04, 0.04, 0.04],
 [0.04, 0.04, 0.05,  ..., 0.05, 0.04, 0.04],
 [0.05, 0.04, 0.04,  ..., 0.04, 0.05, 0.04]])


In [73]: st.normalize(x + 5).len()
Out[73]: ([1.00, 1.00, 1.00])

In [74]: st.normalize(x + 3).len()
Out[74]: ([1., 1., 1.])

In [75]: st.normalize(x).len()
Out[75]: ([1.00, 1.00, 1.00])

#bad, need normalization
In [76]: (x + 3).len()
Out[76]: ([67.13, 67.13, 67.13])


@staticmethod
def len(a,dim=DEF_DIM): return torch.linalg.norm(a,dim=dim)
```

---

I did not want to post this so not to influence possible better solution.. So here is one my attempts .. parts I borrowed from what I found.

This only works for 1D vectors ;(

```
@staticmethod
def fft_normalize(x, dim=DEF_DIM):# Normalize a vector x in complex domain.
    c = rfft(x,dim=dim)
    ri = torch.vstack([c.real, c.imag])
    norm = torch.abs(c)
    print(norm.shape, ri.shape)
    # norm = torch.linalg.norm(ri, dim=dim)
    # if dim is not None : norm = norm.unsqueeze(dim)

    if torch.any(torch.eq(norm,0)): norm[torch.eq(norm,0)] = st.MIN #!fixme
    ri= torch.divide(ri,norm) #2D fails here
    c_proj = ri[0,:] + 1j * ri[1,:]
    rv = irfft(c_proj, dim=dim)

    return rv
```

---

adapted the solution of Thibault Cimic ... seems to work for 1D vectors, but not for 2D

```
@staticmethod
def fft_normalize(x, dim=DEF_DIM, dot_dim=None):# Normalize a vector x in complex domain.
    c = rfftn(x,dim=dim)
    c_conj = torch.conj(c)
    if dot_dim is None : dot_dim = st.dot_dims(c, c_conj)
    c_norm = torch.sqrt(torch.tensordot(c, c_conj, dims=dot_dim))
    c_proj = torch.divide(c, c_norm)
    rv = irfftn(c_proj, dim=dim)
    return rv
```

Comment: What is “the complex domain”? `rfft` computes the real-valued Discrete Fourier Transform. It uses complex values, but you can’t call that “the complex domain”.

Comment: Many things can be called [a complex space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_space). But you want to use the Fourier transform, no? Why? Just as an exercise to understand the Fourier transform? Because it makes no sense to compute the FFT just to normalize data. It makes things more complicated and more expensive.

Comment: FFT normalization is more stable i.e. the operations give more consistent results ... much better

Comment: Why would they? I don’t believe that. What is more consistent than subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation? The FFT adds a lot of complication that leads to floating-point rounding errors, and there is no reason to think it’ll be more consistent.

Comment: because i'm mainly using circular correlation and convolution .. those were just examples for illustration ... and YES FFT norm works better for those ops I tested it  ... and FFT except norm is way, way faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to normalize with the norm associated to the natural complex inner product. So is that what you're trying to do :

```
def fft_normalize(x, dim=DEF_DIM):# Normalize a vector x in complex domain.
    c = rfft(x,dim=dim)
    c_norm = math.sqrt(c.dot(numpy.conjugate(c)))
    c_proj = c/c_norm
    rv = irfft(c_proj, dim=dim)
   return rv
```

Comment: thanks.. have to adapt the code for torch .. and will test ... can i read somewhere what does it mean "norm ... natural complex inner product" OR if u can write more detailed explanation

Comment: @sten As soon as you work with a space H, that has an inner product, ie a scalar product between vectors or sometimes called also the dot product,, let's write it down (u,v) for u and v in H (see scalar product definition here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) you can defined a norm from it, often referred to as the norm-2, as such : ||u|| = (u,u)^{1/2}. Wikipedia section : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Norm_properties
Also, don't know if it' you that voted for my answer, but you shouldn't vote it up if you haven't tested it yet, but thks :)

Comment: why dot product between the vec and the conjugate ... whats equiv in real domain .... is it sqrt(u * u)

Comment: @sten the canonical inner product for real vectors is (u,v) = u . v^t = \sum_{i=0}^{n} u_i * v_i. Hence the norm associated to it is what you wrote : ||u||=sqrt((u,u))=\sum_{i=0}^{n} u_i * u_i. But for complex vector you need to take the conjugate for it to satisfy the condition in the definition of a inner product.